# Can we re-formate the ansible variable output value and again store in variable?

Tags: ansible

I have playbook which is giving me output of mac address,

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "mac_list1": [
            "08:f1:ea:6d:03:3c",
            "08:f1:ea:6d:03:3d",
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

Now I want to re-format in as below expected output should be as it is,

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "mac_list1": [
            "08f1.ea6d.033c",
            "08:f1.ea6d.033d"

        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

How can we do on the fly?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to change the standard macid format to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: register split mac value
  set_fact:
      splitted_mac: "{{ ansible_facts['mac_list1'][0].split(':') }}"
      splitted_mac_one: "{{ ansible_facts['mac_list1'][1].split(':') }}"
 - name: debug rewritten mac
   debug: 
       msg: "{{ splitted_mac[0] }}{{ splitted_mac[1] }}.{{ splitted_mac[2] }}{{ splitted_mac[3] }}.{{ splitted_mac[4] }}{{ splitted_mac[5] }} "

 - name: debug rewritten mac row 2
   debug: 
       msg: "{{ splitted_mac_one[0] }}:{{ splitted_mac_one[1] }}.{{ splitted_mac_one[2] }}{{ splitted_mac_one[3] }}.{{ splitted_mac_one[4] }}{{ splitted_mac_one[5] }} "
```

Please note that this works on the first two elements but you can loop

Comment: This is phrased as a question, and "Answers" are not for followup questions, use comments for that. But either way, [edit your Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61718902/edit) to fix the formatting, since your answer contains code but it is not formatted as code, making it impossible to read

Comment: Hi I have ready store  the output in variable and then store in variable as set_fact.whatever above i have shared that is output from set_fact variable.

Comment: Ok, did you try to do what I wrote on the top? Is it a fixed format of mac_list1, i.e. do you expect always two elements in the list? Is there a rule to rewrite from normal output to your custom output?